# Initialize array in constructor's initialization list

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization

I'm trying to initialize an array in my constructor's intialization list, and I want the array to have the size MAX_SIZE, which is a public static const in my Stack class. How can I get it to work? The compiler complains, saying they have incompatible types in assignment of 'double' to 'double[0u]'

Here is my code:

```
class Stack {
    public:      
          Stack();
          static const unsigned MAX_SIZE; 
    private:
          double array[];
          unsigned elements;     
    };  // class Stack

    Stack::Stack(): array( array[MAX_SIZE] ), elements(0) {}

    const unsigned Stack::MAX_SIZE = 4;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Unless you're completely masochistic: `static const unsigned max_size = 4; std::vector<double> array; Stack::Stack() : array(MAX_SIZE){}`

Comment: Is there a simpler way perhaps? i.e. without using vectors. How can I get the program to accept my array data member with its size being MAX_SIZE?

Comment: I would get used to using `std::vector`. I rarely use arrays; I'll use a `std::vector` be preference nearly every time. The code @Jesse Good has given should work as well.

Comment: There are valid reasons to avoid vector. Vector always initializes on a heap while an array can be initialized over stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 class Stack {
        public:
              Stack();
              static const unsigned MAX_SIZE = 4;
        private:
              double array[MAX_SIZE];
              unsigned elements;
        };  // class Stack

 Stack::Stack():  array(), elements(0) {}
```

But, `std::vector` would be better as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I see.. so, basically, avoid initializing the array in the initialization list. Not possible, correct? Also, is it not possible to write my MAX_SIZE constant after main the way I did?

Comment: Reason I ask is cause I read differently on here, that the definition should be outside of the class:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr038.htm

Comment: `array()` in the intializer list zero initializes all the elements. You are correct, and I didn't define `MAX_SIZE` because I am only using it's value in the code. Define `MAX_SIZE` outside the class if you need to use it elsewhere.

Comment: @Sean: You don't need a separate definition for a `static const <integer type>` variable like you do in other cases.

Comment: @JesseGood Is that array() initialization a standard conforming thing?

Comment: @mezhaka: Yes, this form is called `value initialization`.

Comment: Sorry to revive a old question, but I'm learning C++ and trying to implement a stack as well for learning purposes. So in C++, you have to initialize the size of the array under private? You don't do it in the constructor? I'm a C#/Java guy, so this seems all backwards to me.

Comment: @Kev: `private` is just the access specifier, but yes you need to specify the size as shown above. In C#/Java, arrays are reference types, right? When you create an array in one of those languages, the object is allocated on the managed heap outside of your class. This is why you can do it in the constructor in those languages. In C++, when you have an array as a member of your class, the storage space for that array lives inside any objects of type `Stack`, therefore the size needs to be known before the constructor is ever run.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks for the explanation! Literally spent like a good hour last night trying to figure out how to set the size of my array in my constructor in C++....oops :).